# PHP Statement Should return Multiple objects but only returns one

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

For the life of me, I cannot figure out why the below statement in my PHP script returns only one object. It is a mysql server it is communicating with and I have written this so far:

public function getCustomerinfoByCompanyID($itemID) {

```
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection, "SELECT * FROM $this->tablename where CompanyID=?");
    $this->throwExceptionOnError();

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $itemID);        
    $this->throwExceptionOnError();

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $this->throwExceptionOnError();

    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row->CustID, $row->CompanyID, $row->FirstName, $row->Surname, $row->CellNo, $row->Email);

    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
      return $row;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
```

Now as far as I know, it should return all of my customers that have an CompanyID of variable. However, it just returns the first customer and that is all, nothing else.

Any ideas?

Also, one thing I want to do is concatenate FirstName and Surname, but I am not sure if I can do that in PHP. I am still learning this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
while( mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
   $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you're returning after the first call to mysqli_stmt_fetch() so of course there'll only be one object.
create an array, run mysqli_stmt_fetch() in a while loop and add all rows to the array, then return the array.

looking thru examples is faster than posting here
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

Comment: Thank you for the link, I have read through quite a bit of it and it is starting to make sense.