# SQL statement not returning all values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to pull in a list of values from a table but can't get all of them. Running the following in MySQL returns a list of 3 buildings - (Building A, Building A, Building B) with this query: `SELECT building FROM cms_availabilities`. However I can't get the same results on my page.

```
$sql = "SELECT building FROM cms_availabilities";
$result = $database->query($sql);
$availabilities[] = $database->fetch_array($result);
var_export($availabilities);
```

This returns: `array ( 0 => array ( 0 => 'Building A', 'building' => 'Building A', ), )`

I need to get Building A, Building A, Building B. I'm also not sure why the second key displays "building" instead of 1. Any thoughts on what's going on, or how to successfully pull in the results I want?

Comment: you need to iterate through the result set to get all values. Your current code will put only the first row in the array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php mysqli only returns one row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664659/php-mysqli-only-returns-one-row) also [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490633/php-statement-should-return-multiple-objects-but-only-returns-one) and several others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetch_array` will only fetch the current row - you need to iterate through, fetching *each* row in turn:

```
while ($row = $database->fetch_array()) {
    echo $row['building'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while( $availabilities = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) )
{
   // Enter Code here;
}
```

this will return you an associative array.

However `mysql_*` commands are deprecated so you should use:

MySQLi Version:

```
    while( $availabilities = $result->fetch_assoc() )
    {
         // Your Code here
    }

     // You should free availabilities after you're done with it.
     $availabilities->free();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create something like this :

```
<?php
function building (){
        $query=@mysqli_query($this->db,"SELECT building FROM cms_availabilities");
            while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_object($query)){
            $building=stripslashes($row->building);         
                $show_building = array('building'=>$building);  
            }

        return $this->building=$show_building;  
     }
```